# How to read signing algorithm (like SHA512 etc.) from a kernel module?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kernel, digital-signature, kernel-module

I am trying to read the signing algorithm(like SHA512) of a kernel module. I am using Ubuntu machine with Kernel (3.13.0-68-generic).

I tried using modinfo command, but it doesn't tell me the signature algorithm.

```
$sudo /sbin/modinfo netlinkKernel.ko 
filename:       netlinkKernel.ko
license:        GPL
srcversion:     9FC7512864C356D4A8AD301
depends:        
vermagic:       3.13.0-68-generic SMP mod_unload modversions
```

I need to know which algorithm was used to sign the module. Can someone please let me know the command?

Comment: https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Signed_kernel_module_support

Comment: Thanks, the modinfo example in that wiki shows the algorithm but  the same command doesn't tell me the algorithm in my Ubuntu machine

Comment: did you try `modinfo usbcore | grep '^sig'`

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It may be more appropriate to the related site http://asubuntu.com/ . Consider using the flag link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Good luck.